# how to measure the cost of context switching more precisely

Tags: c, operating-system, context-switch

I am writing some code to roughly measure the cost of context switching. The basic idea is inside the textbook [OSTEP](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/cpu-mechanisms.pdf). And based on the idea, I wrote some code as below:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TIMES 1000
#define BILLION 10e9

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pipefd_1[2], pipefd_2[2];

    struct timespec start, stop;
    clockid_t clk_id = CLOCK_REALTIME;

    // for child and parent process run on the same cpu
    cpu_set_t set;
    int parentCPU, childCPU;

    char testChar = 'a';        /* Use for test */

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s parent-cpu child-cpu\n",
                argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    parentCPU = atoi(argv[1]);
    childCPU = atoi(argv[2]);

    CPU_ZERO(&set);

    if (pipe(pipefd_1) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pipe(pipefd_2) == -1) {
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    switch (fork()) {
        case -1:    /* error */
            perror("fork");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            
        case 0:     /* child process */
            CPU_SET(childCPU, &set);

            if (sched_setaffinity(getpid(), sizeof(set), &set) == -1) {
                perror("set cpu for child process");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            char readChar_c;

            close(pipefd_1[0]);     /* Close unused read end */
            close(pipefd_2[1]);     /* Close unused write end */

            for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; ++i) {
                while (read(pipefd_2[0], &readChar_c, 1) <= 0) {}       /* read to the first pipe */
                write(pipefd_1[1], &readChar_c, 1);                     /* write to the first pipe */
            }

            close(pipefd_2[0]);
            close(pipefd_1[1]);

            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

        default:    /* parent process */
            CPU_SET(parentCPU, &set);

            if (sched_setaffinity(getpid(), sizeof(set), &set) == -1) {
                perror("set cpu for parent process");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            char readChar_p;

            close(pipefd_2[0]);     /* Close unused read end */
            close(pipefd_1[1]);     /* Close unused write end */
            
            clock_gettime(clk_id, &start);
            for (int i = 0; i < TIMES; ++i) {
                write(pipefd_2[1], &testChar, 1);                   /* write to the second pipe */
                while (read(pipefd_1[0], &readChar_p, 1) <= 0) {}   /* read to the first pipe */
            }
            clock_gettime(clk_id, &stop);

            close(pipefd_2[1]);
            close(pipefd_1[0]);

            printf("the average cost of context switching is: %lf nsec\n", ((stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * BILLION
                         + stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec) / TIMES);
    }

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

but I still have some questions about this problem.

1. I've read other's code, and they just use read(pipefd_2[0], NULL, 0) and write(pipefd_1[1], NULL, 0) to perform read and write operation. I am not sure if you have not written some data to pipe1 in one process yet, and you want to read the data through pipe1 in other process, will context switching occur in this situation? or read function just return 0?
2. Since context switching will happen if you read through pipe, the precise cost of context switching should be from leaving that process to entering the other process and not include the time of executing some instructions in later process, so I think use this way to calculate the cost of context switching may not be precise enough. Is this because the execution time is negligible compared to switching contexts?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Note that the majority of the cost of a context switch is side effects (cache misses, TLB misses, etc) that cause the new context's code to run slow after the context switch. For this reason, "ping pong micro-benchmarks" (like you've shown, where the memory footprint is as tiny as possible) severely under-estimate the true cost of typical context switches.

Comment: I think it is just to give students who are new to operating systems an intuitive feeling so it's not that precise. but thanks to your answer!

Comment: To see why it wouldn't make sense for `read` to return 0, remember that Unix is designed so that simple filter programs can be used in pipelines without change.  For a regular file, `read` returns 0 only at end-of-file, so that's how programs recognize EOF.  If reading from a pipe could return 0 merely because the writer had been scheduled out and hadn't written yet, you'd find it very annoying that `cat file | grep foo | sort` sometimes randomly only returned half of the matches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0. `#define BILLION 1e9 //not 10e9`
1. The code is OK. `read()` does *not* return 0 if there's no data in the pipe—it blocks.

   That's why the ping pong you're doing effectively measures the cost
   of context switches (+IO overhead).

   `read()` returns 0  for the read end of a pipe only when all OS-counted references (created
   via `dup*` functions or `fork`ing in conjuction with fd inheritance)
   to the corresponding write end are closed.
2. You're effectively measuring context switches + the pipe's IO overhead. You can measure approximate IO overhead of the pipe separately by adapting the code to use just one pipe on a >=2 core system (so there's almost no context switch per an io call) and making one process a permanent reader and the other a permanent writer (https://pastebin.com/cGDWFdgQ). I'm getting about 2*0.55µs overhead + about 5.5µs for the whole thing so about 4.4µs per context switch).

Comment: Thanks! I have got results similar to yours.

Comment: By the way, after changing read and write function, the cost of context switching + IO overhead(I think since read NULL and write NULL, so it can be negligible) become about 1800 nsec, so I think maybe the IO overhead is more than 500 nsec.

Comment: @shino I think I measured it wrong and was in fact surprised it was that low. The question  here should be  "if read/write is allowed to proceed without blocking, how much will it cost" and I believe I only measured the time for read and forgot about write so it should be about twice as much 2x570ns = 1140ns. Anyway my modified program: https://pastebin.com/cGDWFdgQ. Ran it with `./io 0 1 1000000 0` on two cores so as to avoid blocking.

Comment: Uh...I've found another way to avoid system call using sched_yield method to perform context switch and calculate the time different between two processes.  I think this method is better.

Comment: @shino That may tricky. I'd check to make sure my use of `sched_yield()` was really causing context switches (the 'Voluntary context switches" line in the output of `/usr/bin/time -v ./yourbinary`). A naive loop of `sched_yield()` doesn't do that.

Comment: You are right, a naive loop doesn't make sense. There is a blog that delved into this issue :[context switch](https://blog.tsunanet.net/2010/11/how-long-does-it-take-to-make-context.html)